# SharePoint Pagestatus bar not appearing there is no ribbon available

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, publishing-page

I have a publishing site in SharePoint 2013. I am trying to incorporate page status bar using the following snippet

```
    function addPageStatusMessage() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
    statusID = SP.UI.Status.addStatus("Information", "This is my first status bar", true);
    SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(statusID, "red");
});
```

}

The page status bar appears only in system pages and in pages where the ribbon is loaded. 
Is there some setting where I can have this page status bar even if ribbon is not loaded?

I have the page status bar tag outside the ribbon element.

```
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="DeltaPageStatusBar" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
          <div id="pageStatusBar"></div>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
```

Additional findings

On putting the break-point for any attribute change on pagestatus div, I can see that init.js is being called after my function call and it has a function to remove the status message. I tried to use
         **ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(addPageStatusMessage,"init.js")** 
without any luck.